# React Native Navigation React Native CLI Autolinking error

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

## Issue Description

I installed the library via `npx react-native link react-native-navigation` (and modifying the `minSdkVersion` in `andoid/build.gradle`).

When I run npx react-native run-android, the app is built and works fine, though I get the following error in the terminal:

```
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually: 
  - react-native-navigation (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-navigation")
```

Since the lib has been linked manually, I add an entry in the `react-native.config.js` file to prevent react native to try to autolink the lib, as in:

```
module.exports = {
    dependencies: {
        'react-native-navigation': {
            platforms: {
                android: null, // disable Android platform, other platforms will still autolink if provided
            },
        }
    }
  };
```

Now, the CLI error is not longer shown and the app is successfully built, but I get an error in the emulator:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating "this.nativeCommandsModule.setRoot()").
```

Which comes about at my first `Navigation.setRoot(...);` call:

```
[index.js]

const start = () => {
    Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
        registerScreens();
        gotoInitialising();
        // gotoLogin();
    });
};

start();
```

My question is, what extra step should I take to get the lib to work and to not have a React Native CLI error, at the same time.

## Environment

React Native Navigation version: `6.0.1`
React Native version: `0.61.5`
Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): `Android`
Device info (Simulator/Device? OS version? Debug/Release?): `Android emulator API 28 - (emulator version 29.2.1-5889189) - Debug build`

Comment: The TypeError you're getting is thrown since RNN has not been linked. The issue with minSdk should be resolved in [6.1.0](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#610)

Answer (score 0):

FYI, since react-native-navigation@6.1.0, the link script has been fixed to update the `minSDK` for android as well.

Also you should not add react-native-navigation in `react-native.config.js` as the RNN library is required to be used in your native code. The team has updated the documentation to make the installation guide clearer: https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/installing. If you follow the guide, it should be quite straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

run the following command: `react-native unlink react-native-navigation`